# How to make emacsclient open each file in a separate 'window' within the same 'frame'

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

I am trying to open two files, say 'hello.txt' and 'world.txt' in *emacsclient* from a terminal and I want them to be opened in two different *windows*(as in the emacs sense of the word) but in the same *frame*.

I invoke *emacsclient* like this:

```
emacsclient -nw hello.txt world.txt
```

What presently happens is that a single *emacsclient* frame shows a single window where hello.txt is displayed. The other file, is opened into a buffer which is not visible.

If I instead use *emacs* instead of *emacsclient* I get the intended result(i.e two files get opened within the same frame but in two windows). How can I make emacsclient behave the same way as emacs?

I am not asking for ways to make *emacsclient* spawn multiple frames, rather I was asking for some way to make *emacsclient* to open multiple files in split-windows inside the same frame.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't seem like you can do this directly using emacsclient and a file list

You can achieve the same effect, with a bit of a kludge, by passing lisp to emacsclient to do what you want, although it gets a bit verbose

```
emacsclient -t -e '(progn (find-file "file1")(find-file-other-window "file2"))'
```

You perhaps could wrap this is a little shell script `ec2files.sh`, that takes two parameters and interpolates them into that lisp form.

Or write a defun that you load in emacs init that takes 2 file arguments and opens them.

```
(defun example-split-window-2-files (f1 f2) 
  (find-file f1)
  (find-file-other-window f2))
```

and then invoke that from emacsclient -e

```
emacsclient -t -e '(example-split-window-2-files "file1" "file2")'
```

Answer (score 4):

The variable `server-window` is what you want to look at. You can set this variable to a function that chooses which window to open.

I have the following in my emacs config:

```
(setq server-window 'pop-to-buffer)
```

That ensures that when you open a (single) file it uses another window (creating it if necessary) to display the file. You will need to either find or write a function to pass to server-window that will keep creating new windows for you to display files in.

Answer (score 0):

Section 37.1, "Invoking `emacsclient'", of the emacs 24.3.1 manual says:

> You can also force `emacsclient' to open a new frame on a graphical
>   display, or on a text terminal, using the`-c' and `-t' options.

Comment: This is not what I was asking, I do not want to open new frames, but only a separate window for each of the files.